# Adjusting Craftsman Garage Door Motor Height Travel

Tags: doors, garage

Just bought a new garage door opener and it opens about 6 inches short than what I want it to.  I read about adjusting the travel screws, but this model has no travel screws on it. The model number is 139.54930. What is the proper way to increase the height of the door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the manual](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/user-manuals/13954930-Craftsman-Parts-Garage-Door-Opener-Parts-manual?searchTerm=139.54930). On page 29 it shows the following:

[image]

On page 30 it describes how to check and adjust the reversal mechanism. I suggest that you do so.

Comment: RTFM, always the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

The instructions for this garage door opener are readily available online if you don't have a copy.  The adjustments are done electronically using the control panel on the opener.  See the instructions for detailed directions on how to do this.